# PrimeFaces datatable with dynamic columns of any column content using newer Mojarra 2.1 versions

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, mojarra, view-scope

We are running on Java EE 6 + PrimeFaces 3.5.28 + JSF 2.1.6 (currently) on GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

Our requirement for the datatables is to have dynamic columns, which can basically be of **any content**, that is simple output text, complex output texts, formatted dates, formatted numbers, booleans displaying Yes/No (language-dependent), enums displaying their value labels (language-dependent), buttons, links (see my first comment) - you get the point.

We have solved our requirements with the construct of a `<p:dataTable>` making use of a `<c:forEach>` + `<p:column binding="">`:

```
<p:dataTable id="data"
             widgetVar="resultDataTable" 
             value="#{depotManager.dataModel}"
             var="dep"
             rowKey="#{dep.id}"
             selection="#{depotManager.selectedEntity}"
             selectionMode="single"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rows="#{depotManager.selectedRowsPerPage}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100,200"
             resizableColumns="true"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="90%"
             emptyMessage="#{msg['entity.depot.list.emptyMessage']}">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{depotManager.edit}"
            update=":content-form"
            onstart="mainStatusDialog.show();"
            oncomplete="mainStatusDialog.hide();"
            disabled="#{empty depotManager.entities}" />

    <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.onSort}" global="false" />
    <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.onReorder}" global="false" />
    <p:ajax event="colResize" listener="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.onResize}" global="false" />

    <c:forEach items="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.boundColumns}"
               var="col">                    
        <p:column id="#{col.id}" binding="#{col}" />
    </c:forEach>

    ...
```

This has been the **only** approach that we have ever gotten to work. Call it luck, but it did what our customers wanted (using Mojarra 2.1.6).

This worked for us **until now**. (We also realized, that while our column handler beans are tagged as `@ViewScoped`, they're actually behaving as `@RequestScoped`.)

For a moment, here's the `DepotManagerColumnHandler` bean for the `c:forEach` to iterate over the columns, which basically just contains ALL PrimeFaces `Column` instantiations:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped // behaves request-scoped under Mojarra 2.1.6
public class DepotManagerColumnHandler extends BaseColumnHandler
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected List<Column> newConfigurableColumns()
    {
        DefaultColumnFactory columnFactory = new DefaultColumnFactory( "dep", StringUtils.uncapitalize( this.getClass().getSimpleName() ), EModule.COMPLIANCE );

        List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();

        // content columns
        columns.add( columnFactory.newActiveOutputTextColumn() );

        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "nbr", null, "entity.depot.nbr.header", false, 100 ) );
        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "bank.code", null, "entity.bank.code.header", true, 70 ) );
        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "bank.name", null, "entity.bank.name.header", true, 200 ) );

        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "employee.nbr",
                                               "#{not empty dep.employee ? dep.employee.nbr : ''}",
                                               "entity.employee.nbr.header", true, 80 ) );
        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "employee.firstName",
                                               "#{not empty dep.employee ? dep.employee.firstName : ''}",
                                               "entity.employee.firstName.header", true, 120 ) );
        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "employee.lastName",
                                               "#{not empty dep.employee ? dep.employee.lastName : ''}",
                                               "entity.employee.lastName.header", true, 120 ) );
        columns.add( this.createColumnWithCss( "employee.employeeStatus.name",
                                               "#{not empty dep.employee and not empty dep.employee.employeeStatus ? dep.employee.employeeStatus.name : ''}",
                                               "entity.employeeStatus.singular.header", true, 50 ) );

        return columns;
    }

    private Column createColumnWithCss( String attr, String outputTextExpr, String headerTextMsgKey, boolean removable, int defaultWidth )
    {
        DefaultColumnFactory columnFactory = new DefaultColumnFactory( "dep", StringUtils.uncapitalize( this.getClass().getSimpleName() ),
                                                                       EModule.COMPLIANCE );
        columnFactory.setTooltipEnabled( true );
        return columnFactory.newOutputTextColumn( attr, String.class, outputTextExpr, null, headerTextMsgKey, removable, true, true,
                                                  defaultWidth, true, "#{true}", "overflow-text-hidden", null );
    }
}
```

Here's the super class' `BaseColumnHandler` **relevant** part:

```
public abstract class BaseColumnHandler implements ColumnHandler, Serializable
{
    // recent order of columns as string, e.g. "active nbr code bank-code ..."
    private String       recentOrder;

    private List<Column> boundColumns;

    /**
     * The getter for the Facelet c:forEach. (Will reload and parse the recent order on any request from the UI.)
     */
    public List<Column> getBoundColumns()
    {
        if ( this.boundColumns == null )
        {
            List<Column> shownColumns = new ArrayList<Column>();

            // parse the string of visible columns as getRecentOrder() loaded it from the DB
            String order = this.getRecentOrder().trim();
            String[] columnIds = StringUtils.split( order, ' ' );

            // sub classes must implement newConfigurableColumns()
            List<Column> shownColumns = this.newConfigurableColumns();

            for ( String columnId : columnIds )
            {
                // some filtering going on to filter hidden columns (assume this does what it should)
                ...
            }

            // assign visible columns only
            this.boundColumns = shownColumns;
        }

        return this.boundColumns;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new list of all generally configurable columns.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract List<Column> newConfigurableColumns();

    ...
}
```

Here's a picture of the column handler expressions in place:

[image]

We have to go towards JSF 2.2 and Java EE 7 in the future, so we're currently trying to upgrade to a much more recent Mojarra version, here 2.1.22.

What I tried so far:

1. Upgrading to Mojarra 2.1.22 and leaving the code as-is results in duplicate column ID's, but only when removing columns:

Code:

```
<c:forEach items="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.boundColumns}"
           var="col">                    
    <p:column id="#{col.id}" binding="#{col}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID content-form:data:employee-employee-status-name has already been found in the view.
```

2. Using `<p:columns>`:

If you look at the more complex JSF expressions in `DepotManagerColumnHandler` like `"#{not empty dep.employee ? dep.employee.nbr : ''}"`, this results
in columns displaying an empty string if there's no `employee` relationship present (the employee is optional). The standard PrimeFaces solution to use `p:columns`
as shown in the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml doesn't work (only the header text displays correctly):

Code:

```
<p:columns value="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.boundColumns}"
           var="col">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{col.headerText}"
                      title="#{col.headerText}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{dep[col.property]}" />
</p:columns>
```

We don't automatically have `<h:outputText value="#{dep[col.property]}" />` for each column... we might have columns with buttons or links etc.

Further `<h:outputText value="#{dep[col.property]}" />` cannot work, because there's no way what `col.property` should return for more complex paths `"bank.code"` or even custom expressions `"#{not empty dep.employee ? dep.employee.nbr : ''}"` or `"#{dep.active ? msg['common.yes.label'] : msg['common.no.label']}"`. `col.property` seems to be made for simple paths like `"nbr"`, `"code"` only...

3. Using `<p:columns ... var="col">` while trying to get a binding via `<p:column id="#{col.id}" binding="#{col}">`:

Code:

```
<p:columns value="#{depotManagerColumnHandler.boundColumns}"
           var="col">
    <p:column id="#{col.id}" binding="#{col}" />
</p:columns>
```

This try is quite similar to 1., however this results in an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:566)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:370)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.assignUniqueId(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:172)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
```

**QUESTION**:

How do you solve **dynamic columns in a PrimeFaces datatable** in a Mojarra 2.1.22+ environment having the requirement of **completely custom column content** (best using view-scoped beans)?

BTW, we're also using Seam 3 to get view scope with CDI... `@Named` + `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Well, you say you are using columns with buttons, links, and so on, but in the `createColumnWithCss` method you only create output text columns, right? What am I missing? I have never seen this kind of flexibility requirement in a component, curious. I believe there's a third option which would provide you even more flexibility, using [a custom java-based component](http://jdevelopment.nl/simple-java-based-jsf-22-custom-component/) and writing your own encoder. This way you define the component's rendering behaviour in java, not in xhtml, which is has more restrictions.

Comment: Well, the example I posted is from one of the simpler applications, so in effect the link and button columns aren't shown. As I thought about it, we are **likely** going to get away with the button and link columns as they are usually to the very left or right of the configurable columns. So we might define static `<p:column>`s for them before or after the actual content columns. I updated the question with another example/sub question that is not working (you can omit the button/link column requirement for now).

Comment: Oh and yes, the `createColumnWithCss` is just a local helper method to make the output text content not wrap, but display a ... instead.